# How does current flow when you short base and collector in a current mirror?

Tags: current, analog, current-mirror

I am studying analog electronics and I don't understand how current flows in a current mirror when you short base and collector together.

Electrons are being injected from the emitter into the base when we forward bias the base-emitter junction, but there isn't any reverse bias voltage nor forward bias voltage between base-collector junction only base and collector are connected through a wired connection.

So, how does current reach the collector junction and enter in the collector in the current mirror?

Also, there isn't any reverse bias in the base-collector junction so there will be a lot of recombination when electrons enter from the emitter into base. Won't that make the current mirror less efficient?

Comment: Most of the emitter current comes from the collector and a little tiny bit from the base, as with any active BJT. But you may want to see the details at the semiconductor physics level? I'm not sure from your question. But if so keep in mind that the base is quite thin.

Comment: @jonk yes, conventional way I have this understanding that because base and collector are connected so current will divide into collector and base and becomes total near emitter junction but don't understand how it flows in semiconductor level

Comment: The base layer is very, very thin and it is the more highly doped of the three layers. In this case, the base-collector isn't reverse-biased or forward-biased, but at the same potential. As a forward-biased charge-carrying current transitions from the emitter to the base, drawn by a substantial forward-biased \$J_{\text{E}}\$ junction barrier, it is still true that only a small part of it winds up recombining (a conduction hole and electron pair disappearing.) Most of the charges will still find themselves crossing the \$J_{\text{C}}\$ junction barrier to be collected in the collector region.

Comment: The charges have little reason to migrate back into the base. But if you are looking for a complete discussion of probability, using the Boltzmann factor found in statistical thermodynamics, and taking into account doping and structural details of a 3D device, then I don't think this is the place for it. (My opinion only. Anyone is free to differ.)

Comment: @jonk still thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Electrons are being injected from the emitter into the base

Just to be clear, this implies we are talking about NPN transistors here.

> there isn't any reverse bias voltage nor forward bias voltage between base-collector junction

The electric fields in the base and collector regions are not zero. Electrons that have just crossed the emitter-base junction from the emitter side, are inclined to move toward the (metal) electrodes contacting the semiconductor material of the base and the collector both by the more positive potential of those electrodes relative to the potential of the silicon just past the emitter-base junctiton, and by the higher (net) negative charge density just past the emitter-base junction relative to the metal-semiconductor junctions of the electrodes. The electric field causes drift current, and the charge density gradient causes diffusion current. In this particular case, the drift and diffusion currents are working in concert, rather than in opposition.

> only base and collector are connected through a wired connection.

Well, the base and collector in a diode connected transistor are definitely connected via the wired connection. But they are also connected via the base-collector junction.

> So, how does current reach the collector junction and enter in the collector in the current mirror?

Electrons in an NPN transistor, or minority carriers generally, easily pass across the base-collector junction. A significant difference between the base-collector junction and a reverse biased or zero biased normal diode junction is that the base (when properly biased) has many minority carriers, whereas a reverse/zero biased diode has (compared to the transistor) few minority carriers. If (when) the P region of a reverse biased junction *does* have lots of minority carriers, these pass through the junction easily. (A case where a diode is reverse biased, but *does* have "many" minority carriers occurs when the bias of a diode is suddenly reversed, and there is reverse recovery current. In that case, carriers that have crossed the junction when the diode is forward biased but have not re-combined, easily pass back across the junction when the voltage is reversed).

> Also, there isn't any reverse bias in the base-collector junction so there will be a lot of recombination when electrons enter from the emitter into base.

BJT's are constructed with two properties which favor minority carriers in the base continuing on a journey to the collector. The first factor is that the base is relatively narrow, so that the minority carriers do not have far to travel to reach the collector. The second is that the base is more lightly doped than the emitter. Because of the unequal doping, the density of minority carriers in the base (which have come across the emitter-base junction) is higher than the majority carriers in the base (that come from the base's metal-semiconductor contact). The lop-sided ratio means that many minority carriers will not be recombined in the base, although some will.